# Why does my AQGridView not scroll when cell width is too high?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, aqgridview

I implement the grid view cell size with this method:

```
- (CGSize)cellSize {
   return _gridMode ? CGSizeMake(100, 100) : CGSizeMake(320, 345);
}
```

And check

```
_gridMode
```

for determining which cell to display (either a thumbnail or a full-screen cell).

The full screen cell is supposed to be 320x345.

It draws no subviews wider than 320px.

When I draw the full screen cell, I cannot scroll and when I switch back to grid mode, I see nothing (black screen).

When I set cellSize to 310x345 instead of 320x345, it works -- except my full screen subvies get offset by a few pixels horizontally.

What should I do to display full-screen width AQGridViewCells?

Comment: Can you give more details code?

Comment: Not sure what else I could say that would be helpful.